# Avoid comma expressions and duplicate declarations

Tags: javascript, syntax, duplicate-detection

In order to clear up my code I have been paying attention to all of the hints in Web Storm.  The following `duplicate declaration` errors have confused me.

In the following code, is the double use of `var` necessary (or advised) to prevent a global variable? (or could I remove the second `var` in from of s:

```
function run(x) {
    if(x == 5) {
        var s = 'Yes',
            bar = 1,
            baz = 2
    } else {
        var s = 'No',
            bar = 1,
            baz = 2
    }
    console.log(s);
}
```

Also, if I do remove var in the `else` condition, I get a `comma expression` error, indicating that my code may be "overly clever".

Writing

```
else {
    bar = 1,
    baz = 2
 }
```

Seems to me to be bad syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sticking to the original code, then cleanest solution would be:

```
function run(x) {
    var s, bar, baz;

    if(x == 5) {
        s = 'Yes';
        bar = 1;
        baz = 2;
    } else {
        s = 'No';
        bar = 1;
        baz = 2;
    }
    console.log(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this I would use:

```
function run(x) {
  var s = (x === 5) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  var bar = 1;
  var baz = 2;

  console.log(s);
}
```

You're getting a duplicate declaration error at present because the variables are in the same scope.

Comment: And also, the error in else is because the first var declaration ends with semi-colon. Subsequent comma on bar will produce an error.